# Move files from Listview to new directory in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm trying to write a code in which users can add files to a listview. These files must then be moved to a user specified location. What I can't get to work is the filepath of files that are added to the listview. Here's the code for moving the file:

```
sPath = My.Settings.DefaultPath & ComboBox1.Text & "\" & ComboBox2.Text & "\"
        If txtOnderwerp.Text = "" Then
            If ComboBox3.Text = "Make your choice..." Then
                MsgBox("Select subject!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                Try
                    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(item, sPath & ComboBox3.Text & "\" & item.Text, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)
                        MsgBox("Copy succesfull.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                        ListView1.Items.Clear()
                        Me.Close()
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error copying file: " & ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        End If
```

The code above states an error because 'item' is not a string for the FilsSystem.Copy command. Users can add files to a listview with this code:

```
 Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.Multiselect = True
        If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            For Each fn As String In ofd.FileNames
                Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(fn)
                Dim icons As Icon = SystemIcons.WinLogo
                Dim li As New ListViewItem(fi.Name, 1)
                If Not (ImageList1.Images.ContainsKey(fi.Extension)) Then
                    icons = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)
                    ImageList1.Images.Add(fi.Extension, icons)
                End If
                icons = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)
                ImageList1.Images.Add(icons)
                ListView1.Items.Add(fi.Name, fi.Extension)
            Next
        End If
    End Using
```

Comment: When you add the ListViewItem, put the fi.FullPath into the listitem's tag. Use that later when doing the copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer thanks to advice from Andrew Mortimer.

Code for ListView:
    Dim str(2) As String
        Dim itm As ListViewItem

```
    Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.Multiselect = True
        If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            For Each fn As String In ofd.FileNames
                Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(fn)
                Dim icons As Icon = SystemIcons.WinLogo
                'Dim li As New ListViewItem(fi.Name, 1)
                If Not (ImageList1.Images.ContainsKey(fi.Extension)) Then
                    icons = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)
                    ImageList1.Images.Add(fi.Extension, icons)
                End If
                str(0) = fi.Name
                str(1) = fi.FullName
                icons = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)
                ImageList1.Images.Add(icons)
                itm = New ListViewItem(str)
                ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
            Next
        End If
    End Using
```

Code for copying items in listview:

```
Dim str As String
Dim copyfilename As String
Dim NewDir As String
Try
                    NewDir = My.Settings.DefaultPath & ComboBox1.Text & "\" & ComboBox2.Text & "\" & txtOnderwerp.Text
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(NewDir)

                    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
                        copyfilename = item.Text
                        str = item.SubItems.Item(1).Text
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(str, NewDir & "\" & copyfilename)
                        MsgBox("Kopiëren is gelukt.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                        ListView1.Items.Clear()
                        Me.Close()
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
                End Try
```